# Opening Browser in Android Device for Webpage UI testing

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selendroid, remotewebdriver

Anybody, tell me an way to open firefox and opera browsers in an android device and i have to get driver object for that browser, with the driver object I need to perform several actions on the webpage like, open the URL, getting element locations/positions, clicking the object, verifying the object attributes, etc., I am unsuccessful in using with "RemoteWebDriver" and "Selendroid Driver", so please give me some idea/approach to do it.

Comment: Still not programming related questions? Than this is not your site.

Comment: @greenapps, Please help me, where i can reach to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it in the wrong way. To use an android application in your `selendroid` driver you need to have the .apk file for that application. You can get .apk files for `Firefox` and `Chrome` by searching on `Google Guru` and use them as the application under test. You can load the URL which you want by using

```
 driver.get("Your URL");
```

If you have any problem writing scripts go through documentation at [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io). And in case of further assistance edit your question.